# nothing printed out even for some lines where print() is out of continue block

Tags: python, python-3.x, continue

I have a file `~/practice/search_from` that looks like this:

```
From i
ssdfadfksjaflkf
asdfasf
adf
sd
fd
fs
sgdggggggggggggsd
gsg
sdg
From j
dasdfewf
sdfas
adsf
```

I want to print lines that starts with From.

So I did in the python prompt the following :

```
>>> fhandle=open('practice/search_from')
>>> for line in fhandle:
...    if not line.startswith('From '):
...     continue
...    else:
...     print(line.rstrip())
... 
From i
From j
```

This code seems to work fine.

However, when I put

```
>>> fhandle=open('practice/search_from')
>>> for line in fhandle:
...     line = line.rstrip()
...     if not line.startswith('From:') :
...         continue
...     print(line)
...
```

or

```
>>> fhandle=open('practice/search_from')
>>> for line in fhandle:
...     line = line.rstrip()
...     if not line.startswith('From:') :
...         continue
...     else:
...         print(line)
```

nothing prints out. Why is it like this? Is there a way to fix the last two codes?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your codes are fine, except, you are searching with `From:`.

Remove the `colon(:)` from your codes, and it will work properly:

```
In [2296]: fhandle=open('practice/search_from')

In [2297]: for line in fhandle:
      ...:     line = line.rstrip()
      ...:     if not line.startswith('From'):
      ...:         continue
      ...:     print(line)
      ...:     
From i
From j
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Can I ask you another question? After executing the first for line in fhandle: loop, if I execute the same for loop once more, it prints out nothing. Do I have to open it right before every loops? Thank you very much @Mayank

Comment: Yes, you need to open the fhandle again.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Nothing prints out because no lines in your file start with `From:`.

`line.startswith('From:')` will be `True` only if the line starts with "From:" (including the colon).  Hence `not line.startswith('From:')` will always be `True` in your file (no lines start with `From:`), and you'll always evaluate the `continue` line, which jumps to the next iteration of the `for` loop.